# Geographical heat map of a custom property in R with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, ggmap, gis

The goal is to build something like 
http://rentheatmap.com/sanfrancisco.html

I got map with ggmap and able to plot points on top of it.

```
library('ggmap')
map <- get_map(location=c(lon=20.46667, lat=44.81667), zoom=12, maptype='roadmap', color='bw')
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(100, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(100, mean=44.81667, sd=0.05), price=rnorm(10, mean=1000, sd=300))
ggmap(map) + geom_point(data=positions, mapping=aes(lon, lat)) + stat_density2d(data=positions, mapping=aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill=..level..), geom="polygon", alpha=0.3)
```

[image: stat_density2d on a map]

This is a nice image based on density. Does anybody know how to make something that looks the same, but uses position$property to build contours and scale?

I looked thoroughly through stackoverflow.com and did not find a solution.

**EDIT 1**

```
positions$price_cuts <- cut(positions$price, breaks=5)
ggmap(map) + stat_density2d(data=positions, mapping=aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill=price_cuts), alpha=0.3, geom="polygon")
```

Results in five independent stat_density plots:
[image]

**EDIT 2 (from [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr))**

```
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(10000, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(10000, mean=44.81667, sd=0.05), price=rnorm(10, mean=1000, sd=300))
positions$price <- ((20.46667 - positions$lon) ^ 2 + (44.81667 - positions$lat) ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 10000
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(10000, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(10000, mean=44.81667, sd=0.05))
positions$price <- ((20.46667 - positions$lon) ^ 2 + (44.81667 - positions$lat) ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 10000
positions <- subset(positions, price < 1000)
positions$price_cuts <- cut(positions$price, breaks=5)
ggmap(map) + geom_hex(data=positions, aes(fill=price_cuts), alpha=0.3)
```

Results in:
[image]

It creates a decent picture on real data as well. This is the best result so far. More suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT 3:**
Here is test data and results of a method above:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/artem-fedosov/share/master/kernel_smoothing_ggplot.csv

```
test<-read.csv('test.csv')
ggplot(data=test, aes(lon, lat, fill=price_cuts)) + stat_bin2d(, alpha=0.7) + geom_point() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

[image]

I believe that there should some method that uses other than density kernel to compute proper polygons. It seems that the feature should be in ggplot out of the box, but I cannot find it.

EDIT 4:
I appreciate you time and effort to figure out the proper solution to this seemingly not too complicated question. I voted up both your answers as a good approximations to the goal.

I revealed one problem: the data with circles are too artificial and the approaches do not perform that well on read world data.

Paul's approach gave me the plot:
[image]

It seems that it captures patterns of the data that is cool.

jazzurro's approage gave me this plot:
[image]

It got the patterns as well. However, both of the plots does not seem to be as beautiful as default stat_density2d plot. I will still wait a couple of days to look if some other solution will come up. If not, I will award the bounty to jazzurro as this will be the result I'll stick to use.

There is an open python + google_maps version of required code. May be someone will find inspiration here:
https://github.com/jeffkaufman/apartment_prices

Comment: Did you try something like `positions$price_cuts <- cut(positions$price, breaks=5)` and then using `price_cuts` instead of `..level..` for the fill?

Comment: I have tried it. It produces 5 independent layers with gradient scales :(

Comment: `geom_hex(data=positions, aes(fill=price_cuts), alpha=0.3)` might get you closer to what you're looking for (with some color tweaks)

Comment: Looks very nice, quite close to what I want and without complex data manipulations!

Comment: I have been looking for a way to make polygon smoother. But, I have not found a good solution yet. As you suggested, python seems to offer something to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the map in the link you attached was produced using interpolation. With that in mind, I wondered if I could achieve a similar ascetic by overlaying an interpolated raster onto a ggmap.

```r
library(ggmap)
library(akima) 
library(raster) 

## data set-up from question
map <- get_map(location=c(lon=20.46667, lat=44.81667), zoom=12, maptype='roadmap', color='bw')
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(10000, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(10000, mean=44.81667, sd=0.05), price=rnorm(10, mean=1000, sd=300))
positions$price <- ((20.46667 - positions$lon) ^ 2 + (44.81667 - positions$lat) ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 10000
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(10000, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(10000, mean=44.81667, sd=0.05))
positions$price <- ((20.46667 - positions$lon) ^ 2 + (44.81667 - positions$lat) ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 10000
positions <- subset(positions, price < 1000)

## interpolate values using akima package and convert to raster
r <- interp(positions$lon, positions$lat, positions$price, 
            xo=seq(min(positions$lon), max(positions$lon), length=100),
            yo=seq(min(positions$lat), max(positions$lat), length=100))
r <- cut(raster(r), breaks=5) 

## plot
ggmap(map) + inset_raster(r, extent(r)@xmin, extent(r)@xmax, extent(r)@ymin, extent(r)@ymax) +
  geom_point(data=positions, mapping=aes(lon, lat), alpha=0.2)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzqfu.png

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to change the color or alpha using inset_raster...probably because of my lack of familiarity with ggmap.

**EDIT 1**

This is a very interesting problem that has me scratching my head. The interpolation didn't quite have the look I thought it would when applied to real-world data; the polygon approaches by yourself and jazzurro certainly look much better!

Wondering why the raster approach looked so jagged, I took a second look at the map you attached and noticed an apparent buffer around the data points...I wondered if I could use some rgeos tools to try and replicate the effect:

```r
library(ggmap)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(gplots)

## data set-up from question
dat <- read.csv("clipboard") # load real world data from your link
dat$price_cuts <- NULL
map <- get_map(location=c(lon=median(dat$lon), lat=median(dat$lat)), zoom=12, maptype='roadmap', color='bw')

## use rgeos to add buffer around points
coordinates(dat) <- c("lon","lat")
polys <- gBuffer(dat, byid=TRUE, width=0.005)

## calculate mean price in each circle
polys <- aggregate(dat, polys, FUN=mean)

## rasterize polygons
r <- raster(extent(polys), ncol=200, nrow=200) # define grid
r <- rasterize(polys, r, polys$price, fun=mean) 

## convert raster object to matrix, assign colors and plot
mat <- as.matrix(r)
colmat <- matrix(rich.colors(10, alpha=0.3)[cut(mat, 10)], nrow=nrow(mat), ncol=ncol(mat))
ggmap(map) + 
  inset_raster(colmat, extent(r)@xmin, extent(r)@xmax, extent(r)@ymin, extent(r)@ymax) +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(dat), mapping=aes(lon, lat), alpha=0.1, cex=0.1)
```

[image]

P.S. I found out that a matrix of colors need to be sent to inset_raster to customize the overlay

Comment: Looks very nice! r <- rasterize(polys, r, polys$price, fun=mean) 
returns me an errror: Error in rv[[ii]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: It works without "fun=mean" (it uses default "fun='last'") and returns same picture as you have. What do you think may be a problem?

Comment: Do we really need it? Does not the aggregation do mean computation job?

Comment: I have no idea why rasterize is returning that error. I updated the raster package on my end and I received the same error. the aggregation does most of the work but the mean is useful in rasterize since it calculates the average price at locations where the circles overlap.

Comment: When I initially worked up this solution I placed a bunch of points inside each circle and used rasterize on the points. Turns out rasterize still takes the mean of spatial points...I've started a question to try and get to the bottom of the rasterize polygons problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994474/r-error-in-rasterize-when-used-on-polygons

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach. The `geom_hex` approach is nice. When that came out, I really liked it. I still do. Since you asked something more I tried the following. I think my result is similar to one with `stat_density2d`. But, I could avoid the issues you had. I basically created a shapefile by myself and drew polygons. I subsetted data by price zone (price_cuts) and drew polygons from the edge to zone center. This approach is in the line of EDIT 1 and 2. I think there is still some distance to reach your ultimate goal if you want to draw a map with a large area. But, I hope this will let you move forward. Finally, I would like to say thank you to a couple of SO users who asked great questions related to polygons. I could not come up with this answer without them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggmap)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)


### Data set by the OP
positions <- data.frame(lon=rnorm(10000, mean=20.46667, sd=0.05), lat=rnorm(10000,    mean=44.81667, sd=0.05))

positions$price <- ((20.46667 - positions$lon) ^ 2 + (44.81667 - positions$lat) ^ 2) ^ 0.5 * 10000

positions <- subset(positions, price < 1000)


### Data arrangement
positions$price_cuts <- cut(positions$price, breaks=5)
positions$price_cuts <- as.character(as.integer(positions$price_cuts))

### Create a copy for now
ana <- positions

### Step 1: Get a map
map <- get_map(location=c(lon=20.46667, lat=44.81667), zoom=11, maptype='roadmap', color='bw')

### Step 2: I need to create SpatialPolygonDataFrame using the original data.
### http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606512/create-polygon-from-points-and-save-as-shapefile
### For each price zone, create a polygon, SpatialPolygonDataFrame, and convert it
### it data.frame for ggplot.

cats <- list()

for(i in unique(ana$price_cuts)){

foo <- ana %>%
       filter(price_cuts == i) %>%
       select(lon, lat)

    ch <- chull(foo)
    coords <- foo[c(ch, ch[1]), ]

    sp_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)), ID=1)))

    bob <- fortify(sp_poly)

    bob$area <- i

    cats[[i]] <- bob
}

cathy <- as.data.frame(rbindlist(cats))


### Step 3: Draw a map
### The key thing may be that you subet data for each price_cuts and draw
### polygons from outer side given the following link.
### This link was great. This is exactly what I was thinking.
### http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748852/choropleth-map-in-ggplot-with-polygons-that-have-holes

ggmap(map) +
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.numeric(area)),
                 alpha = .3,
                 data = subset(cathy, area == 5))+
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.numeric(area)),
                 alpha = .3,
                 data =subset(cathy, area == 4))+
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.numeric(area)),
                 alpha = .3,
                 data = subset(cathy, area == 3))+
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.numeric(area)),
                 alpha = .3,
                 data = subset(cathy, area == 2))+
    geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = as.numeric(area)),
                 alpha= .3,
                 data = subset(cathy, area == 1))+
    geom_point(data = ana, aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 0.3) +                              
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = brewer.pal(5,"Spectral")) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20.35, 20.58), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(44.71, 44.93), expand = c(0, 0)) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Property price zone"))
```

[image]