# R: Error in rasterize when used on polygons

Tags: r, raster

Does anyone know why `rasterize` would return the following error when used on polygons:

```
Error in rv[[ii]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Using other common R functions, such as `mean`, also give the same error, but `rasterize` options, such as `'last'`, work fine. I haven't encountered this problem in the past on previous versions of `raster` (currently using raster_2.3-0). I've attached code I grabbed from an example in `?rasterize`:

```
library(raster)

p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(p1), Polygon(hole, hole=TRUE)), 1)
p2 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0)))), 2)
p3 <- Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0)))), 3)
pols <- SpatialPolygons( list( p1 , p2, p3) )

r <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=45)
r <- rasterize(pols, r, fun='sum') # works
r <- rasterize(pols, r, fun=sum) # returns error: "Error in rv[[ii]] : subscript out of bounds"
```

Comment: You either have an object `sum` in your environment which `rasterize` is trying (and, of course, failing) to treat as a closure, or there's no such object, so the `fun` argument returns `NULL` which no doubt fouls things up.  There's a difference between an object name and a character string.

Comment: I never use sum, mean, min, etc for object names, so unfortunately that's not the problem...

Comment: No, it's still the problem- there's nothing at all called "sum" in your environment, so as I said, you've essentially written `rasterize(pols,r,fun=NULL)`

Comment: Ahh, I see what your saying, but 'sum' is the option that works. It's not considered NULL because it is a recognised argument in rasterize, like 'last'.

Comment: Sigh.... please take the time to learn `R` syntax so you understand that `'foo'` means a character string, but `foo` doesn't

Comment: I know the difference between a character string and a function. `?rasterize` clarifies why its argument `fun` accepts a character string: "`fun`    function or character. To determine what values to assign to cells that are covered by multiple spatial features. You can use functions such as `min`, `max`, or `mean`, or one of the following character values: `'first'`, `'last'`, `'count'`, `'sum'`, `'min'` or `'max'`..." Sorry, I should have stated that `rasterize` accepts recognized character arguments but returns an error when you try to use a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package maintainer Robert Hijmans has fixed this issue; for the time being you can install the updated package from R-forge (install.packages("raster", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")) and the updated version should be on CRAN next week. For the record, I just emailed Hijmans yesterday and he was very responsive in getting this addressed.